# This picture represents one word. Which word is it?

Tags: rebus

[image: one word]

This picture represents one word. Which word is it? 
[Source](https://brainyyou.com/can-you-solve-this-one-word-puzzle-yhzld/)

Comment: Why the downvote? +1 for consolation

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Votes should *not* be for "consolation", but on the quality of the puzzle. This is a puzzle stolen directly from somewhere else (and not a particularly good one, IMO), so it has been downvoted.

Comment: I believe that it has properly sited the source and the puzzle is not that bad as you have said, never mind though, thank you for your reminder

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These may combine to give

> Neptune

With the individual images clueing

> 1. Yen - Y ← NE
>  2. top of Pen → P
>  3. Tuna - Na (sodium) → TU
>  4. Rest of Pen (upside down) ← NE

Comment: ROT13: V jbhyq fnl gung gung svfu vf n pbq, abg n ghan. Gung guerj zr bss.

Comment: @Arthur ROT13: ol gur funcr bs gur svaf vg vf vaqrrq n pbq naq abg n ghan

Comment: Arthur and casualcoder are right, so image 3 or answer is fishy.

Comment: ROT13: vs 2 vf gur gbc bs gur cra, ubj pna 4 or hcfvqr qbja?

Comment: @Nank, that is a philosophical question. If the cap was on, then the whole object would be pointing up. With the cap off, 2 is still up (and only refers to the tip of the word), but now the rest of the object is pointing upsidedown in the sense that it's not the right way up for using?

Comment: That fish has the wrong number of fins to be a tuna.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm thinking the premise and question are wrong, since we already know...
>  ["A picture is worth a thousand words."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words) .
>
>  Therefore, if the question is asking for 1 answer, there are still 999 more to go along with it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. Please familiarise yourself with the rules of the site. Also, you need to hide your answers in spoilers.